# Sharepoint: Add List from another site

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to add a List on the root site to a sub sub site. Tried with Sharepoint Desginer but get the could not be opened error message.

Comment: Which rights do you have? Site Administrator? Site Owner?

Comment: In the browser I am only shown the lists inside the current site.

Comment: Can you access all the sites or only the top-level site?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Designer, it works the same way as the browser.  You can add lists to the site you are currently on.  I'm not seeing a way in SPDesigner 2007 to choose the location of where my list is (different web).

Verify the url is correct on the subsite and browse to it...then create your list.  You will recieve an access denied message if you do not have sufficient rights (versus a 404-like error).